# Can't get the exponent operation button to work in a calculator

Tags: c#

I've been working through a calculator tutorial to attempt to branch out into C# and I've run into a snag. I can't get the exponent button to function properly. Everything else that I've set up so far works fine (+,-,*,/) but I've tried 2 different methods from 5 or 6 different posts I've found about this subject and nothing seems to work. The issue seems to be there's a disconnect at the button level, but the button that calls the operation is coded exactly the same as the others so I'm not sure why it's not working. My second attempt is below.

```
namespace CS_Calculator
{
    public partial class calculatorform : form
    {
        string input = string.Empty;
        string operand1 = string.Empty;
        string operand2 = string.Empty;
        char operation;
        double result = 0.0;
        public calculatorform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   //Set button 2
            this.box_result.Text = "";
            input += "2";
            this.box_result.Text += input;
        }

    private void btn_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   //Set button 3
            this.box_result.Text = "";
            input += "3";
            this.box_result.Text += input;
        }

    private void btn_exp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   //Codes Exponent button
            operand1 = input;
            operation = 'E';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

    private void btn_res_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   //Codes Return button 
            operand2 = input;
            double num1, num2;
            double.TryParse(operand1, out num1);
            double.TryParse(operand2, out num2);

            this.box_result.Text = "";
            this.input = string.Empty;
            this.operand1 = string.Empty;
            this.operand2 = string.Empty;

            if (operation == 'E')
            {
                double power = num2;
                for (int i = 1; i <= Math.Abs(power); ++i) ;
                    result *= num1;

                if (power > 0)
                    result = 1 / result;
                box_result.Text = result.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt 1:

```
if (operation == 'E')
{
    result = Math.Pow(num1,num2);
    box_result.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

As an aside, I am completely new to C# and barely have an understanding of the syntax or flow. I'm most familiar with VBA and so far C# feels completely different in almost every regard so please explain your answers in as much detail as possible as this will help me to understand them without having to ask too many follow up questions.

Comment: Can you expand on "Can't get it to function properly". Is it not running your event handler code? Is it giving the wrong result? Is it throwing an exception? Something else?

Comment: Side note: It would be a good idea to dedicate some time learing how to use the debugger. It will be the most valuable tool for you (i am NOT exaggerating here) to get a grip of what your code is doing and helps you validating your assumptions about what (intermediate) results it produces at every step. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger

Comment: Apologies. I've stepped through the code several times and it stops when the operation is called. Basically I enter the first number, press the exponent button and nothing happens. I can't step any further.

Comment: "_nothing happens_" What would you expect to happen? Do you have a breakpoint in the btn_exp_Click method? Is the breakpoint active/enabled? Are you running a "debug build" in the debugger?

Comment: I have a breakpoint set at `operand1 = input;`.  I'm not sure what you mean by "debug build". It's not a production build or anything, just an exercise from a tutorial. For "_nothing happens_" basically when the exponent button is selected it's supposed to write the current value in the result box to operand1 and then when the second value is entered that value is supposed to replace what's in the result box and becomes operand2. When I enter the second value, it adds it to the string the result box rather than replacing it. The button being disconnected is the underlying issue I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt does not work because the loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Math.Abs(power); ++i) ;
    result *= num1;
```

does nothing. That's because a semicolon without an expression in front of it is an operation that does nothing. So you should remove the semicolon in this case:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Math.Abs(power); ++i)
    result *= num1;
```

The same goes for other statements like `if`, `while` and `lock`. All of them expect a statement after the header, e.g.:

```
if (<expression>) <statement>
while (<expression>) <statement>
for (...) <statement>
lock (<expression>) <statement>
```

A statement is code that does not return a value can be one of the following:

- an expression (i.e. code that returns a value) ending with a semicolon: `<expression> ;`
- an empty statement (a NO-OP), which does nothing: `;`
- a compound statement, which executes several statements in a sequence: `{ <statement> <statement> ... }`
- some other statement like `if`, `for`, `while`, etc.

Another problem with your first attempt is that the `result` variable is initialized with zero. And zero multiplied with another number stays zero of course. You should initialize it with one because it is the neutral element of the multiplication.

Comment: Also I assume that not using the `Math.Pow(number, power)` function is for learning purposes that would avoid that logic in any case.

Comment: Thanks Cephus, this is broken down perfectly and is easy to understand. I think the underlying issue though is that the command button to call the exponent calculation is somehow disconnected, but I'm not sure how since the object names match and the button itself is coded exactly the same as the other operators that work perfectly fine, just with a different operation being called `operation == "E"` rather than `operation ==  "+"` for example.

Comment: @cyborg That and also I read in another post that `Math.Pow` is slower below a power of 10 than running the calculation as a loop. The tutorial I used to set up the calculator didn't have an exponent button so i'm trying to add it in myself.

Comment: @SteveJoppich How did you add the click event handler? Did you just write the code? Or did you make a double click on the command button in the designer?

Comment: @Cepheus To be perfectly honest I don't remember. I believe I double-clicked it since I was setting up all of the buttons at the time and I had the thought that it was just faster to double click everything on the front end and code all at once rather than clicking on each button as I wrote the code for it. Could it make a difference copy/paste vs. double click?

Comment: @SteveJoppich Yes, it does. If you make a double click, a code in a different file is created which connects the button to your function.

Comment: @Cepheus if double clicking creates a line in the form1.designer.cs file then that line is there. `this.btn_exp = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();`

Comment: @SteveJoppich You can also use the property window to create an event handler: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8461e9b8-14e8-406f-936e-3726732b23d2

Comment: @SteveJoppich There should also be another line, something like `this.btn_exp.Click += ....`

Comment: @Cepheus Adding the `btn_exp_Click` event to the click event handler on the button itself worked. I'm running through the debugger again to find out why I got infinity as a result, but at least it ran through to the operation.

Comment: @SteveJoppich Glad to hear that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183025/discussion-between-steve-joppich-and-cepheus).